# On board signal termination

Tags: pcb, signal, termination

and thanks for bothering with my problem.

I have a two signals **A** and **B** that I want to route using several alternative paths via jumpers on my board. In one of the occasions I need to use the same input pin of an IC. Rest assured, when signal **A** goes to the IC pin, signal **B** goes to a different place. Please see the image attached:
[image: trace layout]
The trace between the jumper pad and the IC pin is about 24 mm long. My question is, do I need some kind of termination for these traces in order to prevent reflections from the end that is not used at the moment?

The signals are about 3 V in amplitude, with rise/fall time about 0.7 ns, and are between 5 and 15 ns long.

Thanks,

ps. image annotation added

Comment: Did you consider simulating the setup with a HS simulator like Hyperlinx?

Comment: @claudio-avi-chami, no. I do not have any simulators, can you recommend some free tools for that?

Comment: I think that you can download Hyperlynx for evaluation for free - https://www.mentor.com/pcb/product-eval/hyperlynx-si-virtual-lab

Comment: 24 mm is just on the edge of the "1/10 of a rise-time" rule for ignoring distributed effects. Can you move U11 closer to your jumpers to reduce the length? Can you slow down the rise time? Can you accept some ring in the signal? Can you add some attenuation somewhere?

Comment: Any chance you can annotate / mark-up that image with A/B callled out/drawn out? You are correct, you're gonna have to think about termination, but I think there is a more optimal way to layout what you have drawn. That dual trace going into Pin 1 will not work well though, I can tell that right now -- huge stub.

Comment: @ThePhoton, thanks for the comment, at the moment there are components (not shown) that prevent U11 to be placed closer. No degradation of the rising edge of the signal is acceptable, however som ringing should not be a problem. How would attenuation help?

Comment: @KrunalDesai, thanks for your comment. Annotations dully added :) What would you do instead of dual trace to pin1?

Comment: Attenuation provides a way to get the energy out of the system, so it reduces the ringing. If U11 provides on-chip termination, that will also help, otherwise you might want to add termination near the pin of U11 (even though this is in the middle of the line and you will still get a ring off the stub to the unused connector.

Comment: Can you move JP_A and JP_B closer together so that pin 4 of JP_ is closer to R2 ? That will reduce the stub from SMA. If you connect pin 2 of each JP_ together, and then T off from that connection, you'll have a small stub compared to what you have now.

Comment: @efox29 Thanks for your comment!
I actually have other components inside that triangle, so it is not possible to move the jumpers closer together. One major constrain is that all **A||B** traces should be identical lengths.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Forgive my bad drawing. So what's happening is  that you have the opportunity for multiple reflection paths.

In your original setup, if CH_A is active, you have your signal going doing A, and when it gets to ABC node, you have a bit of your signal going to B, and then to C because your impedance halves at this point since you have Zo going to B and Zo going down C (assuming your traces are the same thickness - hard to tell). When each of those reaches the end, they reflect back and it goes all over the place because once you get back to ABC, your impedance changes. This is your ringing. Will this degrade your edge - probably not. A simulation would probably be your best bet.

but if you connect your trace like in D, then there is only one reflection path (which is good!).

so if you have a series termination for CH_A and CH_B, the signal will die out once it reaches the driver.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do I get it right, that the trace **D** in your drawing is connecting the IC pin directly the pad 2 on both the jumpers and without the _star_ point as in my drawing?

Comment: @lazaraza yup. Trace D replaces the star/ABC connection you have.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to "guarantee" a particular circuit operation, you have to take "all" precautions possible.  If your circuit is sensitive to EMI (external or its own), you have to: terminate inputs and outputs, decouple voltage pins, and shield the circuit.  Your circuit may need one or all of these measures.